# Is there a way to force Vault GUI client doing an auto-check out of modified files?

Tags: sourcegear-vault

I feel very comfortable with the way that svn/cvs automatically detects the files which were modified, so that i can see the complete change-set recursively from the root.

Is there a workaround to have the same thing in Vault client?

For any files you changed, would like to show them up as edited and be listed in the pending change set, ready to be checked in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment at your post so I am going to post this as an 'answer'.

I am not sure how to do that for any files but that feature is available in for files edited in Visual Studio (code files etc which is under source control of course).

For Visual Studio 2010 the option is found under Tools > Options,
then select the Source Control tree view on the left tab view, and lastly Integration Options. From the dropdown box under the option **When check out is required, on edit:** > Choose **Automatically Check Out**.

Hopes this helps. If not the [Sourcegear forum](http://support.sourcegear.com/viewforum.php?f=5) will be a good place to ask for support.